# Tile-Map drawing canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have a 100x100 px Tile Map. When I try to open my game on my browser the page freezes because there are to draw 10000 tiles. How can you draw so much tiles without problems. 
My draw() function:

```
this.draws = function(){

    for(j = 0; j < 10000; j++){

        this.i = levels[1][1][j] - 17*Math.floor(levels[1][1][j]/17)
        game.ctx.fillStyle = "red"
        game.ctx.drawImage(game.tiileset,(this.i-1)*this.cellW,(Math.floor(levels[1][1][j]/17))*16,this.cellW,this.cellW,(j-100*Math.floor(j/100))*this.cellW-1,(Math.floor(j/100)+1)*this.cellW,this.cellW,this.cellW)


    }

}
```

Comment: You should only be drawing what would be on screen at the time.  Make it fill in as they scroll around.  If you scaling it down, the images should have lesser versions that are rendered at different zoom ranges.

Comment: All the Math.floor(...) are to crop the right image and put that in the right position. levels[1][1] is the array of the tilemap levels[1][1][j] is the current tile ID in the for loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I´m unsure of what you´re trying to do but it looks like you´re drawing each pixel from the image to the canvas.

If that is indeed the case I suggest you just draw the whole image at once.

If not, I would really need a more elaborated question perhaps with more explanations on the math in your code.

Oh yes don´t forget semicolons.

Comment: I draw each tile of the image to the canvas like it should be done in a tilemap.

Comment: I see maybe this will help you (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Games/Techniques/Tilemaps) it has a performance section